# Loop through text to change the color of each letter using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops

How do I change the color of the letter that is currently "selected" when looping through text like `M00110100N00000000P`?

For example, in a `for` loop, when `i` = 1 I need to change first letter in a word to yellow color. Then when `i` becomes 2, the first letter becomes black again and second letter becomes yellow, etc. I want to use `setTimeout` to make a delay so the change is visible.

I tried to do it using this method but as my "word / line" is made out of numbers like 0 and 1 it doesn't work.

```
function myFunction() {
        var letters = document.getElementById('text');
        for (var i = 0; i < letters.innerHTML.length; i++) {
            //only change the one you want to
                letters.innerHTML = letters.innerHTML.replace(letters[i], '<span style="color: yellow;">'+letters[i]+'</span>');
           }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to do? Your `myFunction` is trying to change all the letters, because it is looping through all the letters  and changing them. If you don't want to change all the text at once, can you explain exactly what you do want to do?

Comment: Yeah, that was probably bad example, but basically I want color indicate on which element Iam right now (using settimeout to make it visual). So basically according to i in the FOR loop I change color of certain "letter / number". EXAMPLE: M00110100N00000000P, each time it loops, color of different number changes.

Comment: OK, you really should have included the info about the timeout in your question so we understood what you wanted :) I've updated my answer to do what you want now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with what you are doing. You can get it working like this - see how it works in the comments, and an explanation of what was going wrong below:

```js
var textElement = document.getElementById('text');
colourCycle(textElement);


/* function: changeLetter
takes the whole word and the position of the current letter 
and wraps that letter with a span to change the colour */

function changeLetter(textToChange, pos){

    // if the pos is the same as the length, we're at the end so return the plain word
    if (textToChange.length == pos) return textToChange;

    // split the text at the letter and insert the span around the letter
    return textToChange.substring(0, pos) 
           + '<span style="color:yellow;">' + textToChange[pos] + '</span>' 
           + textToChange.substring(pos+1);
}

function colourCycle(textElement) {
    // make a copy of the text to work from
    var letters = textElement.innerHTML;  
    
    // for each letter, call our function to change the colour of the letter after 1 sec delay
    // NOTE: we loop 1 extra time so we can remove the colour on the last loop
    for (var i = 0; i <= textElement.innerHTML.length; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                textElement.innerHTML = changeLetter(letters, i);
            }, 1000 * i);
        })(i);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="text">HELLO</div>
```

**How This Works**

**1. We create a function that will wrap the letter at the specified position** with a `span` with the CSS to change the colour.

Note that instead of using `replace` (where we can't choose the position of the letter to replace), we use `substring` to split the string at the position of the letter, then rebuild the string with the span tags around the letter:

```
function changeLetter(textToChange, pos){
    return textToChange.substring(0, pos) 
            + '<span style="color:yellow;">' + textToChange[pos] + '</span>' 
            + textToChange.substring(pos+1);
}
```

**2.  In our main function, create You need to use a copy of the innerHTML** Otherwise you are changing the position of the letters - when you add the `<span...` html, the letter position has changed.

```
var letters = textElement.innerHTML;
```

**3. Set the timeout to change each letter for a second** - when loop through each letter, set a timeout delay of 1 second before we call the `changeLetter` function on the next letter:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= textElement.innerHTML.length; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            textElement.innerHTML = changeLetter(letters, i);
        }, 1000 * i);
    })(i);
}
```

**4. Reset the color to the default at the end** To do this we need to loop one extra time to replace the text with the last yellow letter.

In the loop, we loop up to `i` <= length:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= textElement.innerHTML.length; i++)
```

And add this line to the start of in the `changeLetter` function:

```
if (textToChange.length == pos) return textToChange;
```

Answer (score -1):

you want to add if and else loop show below.

```
function myFunction() {
        var letters = document.getElementById('text');
        for (var i = 0; i < letters.innerHTML.length; i++) {
            //only change the one you want to
                if (i==1){letters.innerHTML = letters.innerHTML.replace(letters[i], '<span style="color: yellow;">'+letters[i]+'</span>');}
else { letters.innerHTML = letters.innerHTML.replace(letters[i],+letters[i]+'</span>');
           }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Giving an answer is good. But explaining what did you do and what was wrong is better. As posting code by itself is not relevant. So please edit your answer to add description

Comment: `if (i=1)` makes for a nice potential infinite loop.